# jQuery add and remove variable from url on a link click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am working on a web application where I need to add and remove variables from the URL. I have done on click adding variables to the URL but I it adds duplicates variable.

```
href="http://localhost<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>?budget=1-lakh-3-lakh"
```

First Click on link:

```
http://localhost/auto/search.php?budget=1-2L
```

Second Click on same link:

```
http://localhost/auto/search.php?budget=1-2L&budget=1-2L
```

I want to remove variable  from the URL if it is already exist else add variable on a link click.
I already tried lot's of method but I am not getting the result. With jQuery I tried `replace(), indexOf()`.

Comment: Are you submitting a form or using a link <a>? If the href of a "a" tag is define as above, the variables will not be added after the existing one.

Comment: I am using link, In general on same link click I want to add or remove some parameters from the link. On each click page will get refreshed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a code to remove a specific parameter from an URL :

```
var url = location.href.replace(/&?budget=([^&]$|[^&]*)/i, "");
```

or the function :

```
function removeParameterFromUrl(url,parameterName)
{
    var reg = new RegExp('&?'+parameterName+'=([^&]$|[^&]*)','gi');     
    return url.replace(reg, ""); 
}

location.href = removeParameterFromUrl(location.href,'budget')
```